# Survival analysis- how to assess the relative difference between two pairs of survival curves?

Tags: r, survival, biostatistics

I am working with a model organism, and we are interested in looking for difference in the effect on survival of both genotype and treatment.
For example, we would like to know if there is a larger relative difference in genotype A for a given treatment than for genotype B, something like ((A treated vs A untreated) vs (B treated vs B untreated)).

What would be the most appropriate way to get at this? I am using the *survival* package in R, so should I just include the interaction of genotype and treatment in the formula in survdiff()?

I've done quite a bit of survival analysis before, but usually only with varying one factor at a time, so this is new territory for me, and searching did not seem to turn up much literature on this issue in particular.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can fit a Cox model and test for all sort of contrast in the same way that you would with a linear model. See `coxph()` for that. Of course, the assumption of proportional hazards kicks in, but there is usually a price to pay for more complex modeling.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but would like to share my opinion. It seems to me you are trying to determine interaction of treatment and genotype. Then you may need to build certain models and add an interactive term to test for the interactive effect.
I use SAS and there are certain ways to address the issue, and I believe R also has such power.

Comment: Sorry, but you basically restated the contents of my question, which is not particularly helpful.